# count number of times a value occurs in a dictionary of lists, where keys are number of occurrences

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I would like to know how many times each item in a list occurs, in a dictionary of lists.  The keys are the number of occurrences per value, and the value can occur across multiple keys.

So,

```
{1: ['intel', 'mail', 'com'], 50: ['yahoo', 'com'], 900: ['google', 'mail', 'com'], 5: ['wiki', 'org']}
```

Would contain

- 1 + 50 + 900 + 5 `com` values, for a total of 956 `com` values in the dictionary,
- 1 + 900 `mail.com` values
- 1 `intel.mail.com` value
- 5 `wiki.org` values

and so on.

I'm trying to solve [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/subdomain-visit-count/), and I decided to make everything into a dictionary:

```
        cpdomains = ["900 google.mail.com", "50 yahoo.com", "1 intel.mail.com", "5 wiki.org"]
        
        split_number = [x.split(' ') for x in cpdomains]
        
        domain = {int(x[0]): x[1].split('.') for x in split_number}
```

gave me that dictionary.

Comment: are you having any problem with the code?

Comment: @komatiraju032 I just dont know what to do next -- how do I count up the number of times each value occurs?  Am I approaching this in a solvable way?

Comment: use combinations

Comment: Had not heard of combinations, I will check it out! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Counter object (from collection) with reduce (from functools) to accumulate all word counts into a big Counter dictionary with the totals:

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce


countWords = {1: ['intel', 'mail', 'com'], 
             50: ['yahoo', 'com'], 
            900: ['google', 'mail', 'com'], 
              5: ['wiki', 'org']}

toCounter  = lambda cw: Counter({w:cw[0] for w in cw[1]})
wordCounts = reduce(Counter.__add__, map(toCounter,countWords.items()) )

print(wordCounts)

Counter({'com': 951, 'mail': 901, 'google': 900, 
       'yahoo': 50,  'wiki': 5,      'org': 5, 'intel': 1})
```

Comment: I'm still learning how to use lambda, and I've never seen reduce.  Very interesting, thank you!